# ubuntu 14.04 crontab does not run simple scripts

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I have created primitive test script just to create directory, to see if crontab works:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir test_folder
exit
```

script is located here `/home/root/test/test.sh`

I made this script executable with:

```
sudo chmod u+x test.sh
```

when I run the script manualy `sudo /home/root/test/test.sh`
the "test_folder" is created. However when I add it to crontab than nothing happens!

I opened crontab with `sudo crontab -e` and I added following rules:

```
00 * * * * /home/root/test/test.sh
10 * * * * /home/root/test/test.sh
20 * * * * /home/root/test/test.sh
30 * * * * /home/root/test/test.sh
40 * * * * /home/root/test/test.sh
50 * * * * /home/root/test/test.sh
```

when I check crontab with `sudo crontab -l` I can clearly see that rules are there, but folder is NOT created! Script just doesnt run!

Later I found that problem may be with the dot in script name... so I changed the name from `test.sh` to `test_sh` ... made it executable with sudo `chmod u+x test_sh`,tried it manualy, test folder was created... than I added to crontab `sudo crontab -e` :

```
00 * * * * /home/root/test/test_sh
10 * * * * /home/root/test/test_sh
20 * * * * /home/root/test/test_sh
30 * * * * /home/root/test/test_sh
40 * * * * /home/root/test/test_sh
50 * * * * /home/root/test/test_sh
```

But again nothing... What am I doing wrong? This is a primitive script, it should run without problems! Did I forgot on something?

EDIT:
Thank you all... especialy heemayl and Gauthier: "***Try to give a full path in your script (`mkdir /home/root/test/test_folder`).***" it did the trick... now it seems that script works ...so no relative dirs... THANKS a LOT

Comment: Where do you expect the folder to be created?  Do you know from where the script is executed, when run fron cron? Try to give a full path in your script (`mkdir /home/root/test/test_folder`).

Comment: Also, you can replace the 6 rows in your crontab with a single row: `*/10  *  *  *  *  /home/root/test/test.sh`.

Comment: try `sudo chmod 775 test.sh`

Comment: assuming that root's home directory is /root (it is on my 16.04 system) I would expect that you should find a directory /root/test_folder

Comment: well script is located at  /home/root/test/test_sh so I think it should be executed from here...

Comment: Try to give a full path in your script (mkdir /home/root/test/test_folder) did the trick... so no relative dirs... THANKS a LOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `root`'s home directory, the directory `test_folder` is created there, precisely `/root/test_folder`. Note that, you have put the script in `root`'s `cron` table by doing `sudo crontab -e` so the directory would be `/root/test_folder`.

`cron` defaults to the home directory of the running user (`root` in this case) before running any task, so as you have a relative path i.e. only `test_folder`, the directory will be created in `root`'s home directory.

This is also similar to other cases where relative paths are used inside a script, and one runs the script from another location; The `PWD` will always refer to the directory from where the script is being run, not where the script is stored.

Note that, the `exit` at the end is redundant.

Comment: yop... its there... thanks a lot for pointing that out :)